# multiple strings replacements on variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

does bash support multiple strings replacement on a variable at once?

on a variable (example V variable) I want to replace XXXXXXX with a string1, YYYYY with a string2 and ZZZZZZZ with a string3

Is it possible to run 1 such relpacement command instead of the 3 run below?

```
$ V="AAAAAAA/XXXXXXX/BBBBBB/YYYYY/CCCCCC/ZZZZZZZ"
$ V=${V//XXXXXXX/string1}
$ V=${V//YYYYY/string2}
$ V=${V//ZZZZZZZ/string3}
$ echo $V
AAAAAAA/string1/BBBBBB/string2/CCCCCC/string3
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it like below:-

```
V=$(echo "$V" | sed 's/XXXXXXX/string1/g;s/YYYYY/string2/g;s/ZZZZZZZ/string3/g')
```

How will it work? `sed` command will search for sting XXXXXX and replace it with string2, replace string YYYYYY with string2 and finally replace ZZZZZZZ with string3 and store the new string into variable V.

So now check the result like below:-

```
echo $V
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easier if you use `sed`.

```
V=$(echo $V | sed -e 's/XXXXXXX/string1/' -e 's/YYYYY/string2/' -e 's/ZZZZZZZ/string3/')
```

Comment: There are missing slashes (after string2 and after string3)

Comment: I got `sed: -e expression #2, char 15: unterminated 's' command`

Comment: Try it now.  Forgot the terminating slashes

Comment: Now it's ok.....

Answer (score 1):

@Abhijit's answer is very OK (the sed option `/g` corresponding to the Bash `//` substitution for replacing all occurrences) but note that in Bash you can avoid the echo and the pipe by doing:

```
V=$(sed -e 's/XXXXXXX/string1/g;s/YYYYY/string2/g;s/ZZZZZZZ/string3/g' <<< $V)
```

This feature is actually called a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings).